# how can i execute a node.js in cmd prompt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, bash

I am newbie in Node.js and started making hello world exercise. I have run into a problem, it is that I make a file with code 'console.log ("Hello World");' and saves it as a test. Then I open it in cmd and write node and then the node test, but for this answer ..... do not know why it does it, although I expect Hello World? I've tried and looking at the internet but can not find an answer to it.

I have install git and node.js.

hope someone can help me?

Comment: You wrote >$ node <filename>.js while in the same directory of it (the file)?

Comment: *"this answer"* ? What answer ? I don't understand your problem.

Comment: question is why i get the ... answer when i run node.js file with this code: console.log("Hello World"); in node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Save the **helloword.js** file into a directory of your choice for example the folder "**home**"

2.Go to the directory in command prompt where the **"helloword.js"** file is by with cd:

```
cd home
```

3.You can test if the file is there by typing:

```
ls (mac)

dir (windows)
```

4.If the file is there simply write

```
node helloworld.js
```

and you should be good!:)

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you save your file in `/home/toto/example.js with :

```
console.log('Hello World');
```

You just launch that by :

```
nodejs /home/toto/example.js
# or
cd /home/toto/
nodejs example.js
```

If the command nodejs is not found, test with the command `node`. It depend of your installation package.

```
node /home/toto/example.js
# or
cd /home/toto/
node example.js
```

Comment: *"I open it in cmd"* => OP is probably on windows

Comment: in windows, i think you should add the nodejs directory in your PATH var